# How to push an object in an array, using react hooks and typscript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I know this is completely a noob question and I'm sorry but I try to figure out how should I manage to put the Object in the state array when submitting the form. Thank you

```
interface newList {
  name: string;
}

const ListAdder = () => {
  const [listName, setListName] = useState("");
  const [listArray, setListArray] = useState<any>([]);

  const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const myNewList: newList = {
      name: listName,
    };

    setListArray([...listArray].push(myNewList));
    setListName("");
    console.log(listArray);
  };

  const listNameHandler = (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setListName(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <label>Create your List</label>
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="List name is..."
          value={listName}
          onChange={listNameHandler}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add the List</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Change this `setListArray([...listArray].push(myNewList));` to `setListArray([...listArray, myNewList]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are saving the result of the push, the new length, instead of the updated array.

```
setListArray([...listArray].push(myNewList)); // <-- saves result of push, [].length
```

You can `concat` the new element:

```
setListArray([...listArray].concat(myNewList));
```

Or just append it

```
setListArray([...listArray, myNewList]);
```

Additional semi-related issue, you can't console log the state and expect to see it immediately updated.

```
setListArray([...listArray, myNewList]);
console.log(listArray); // <-- still current state
```

React state updates are asynchronous, so logging the state like this will only ever log the state from the *current* render cycle ***and not*** the enqueued state for the *next* render cycle. If you want to log state after an update use an `useEffect` hook with dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(listArray);
}, [listArray]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the details and works. Just one thing, which type should I use in place of <any> in the state declaration?

Comment: @Mugi I'm not super familiar with Typescript, but from what I can tell, maybe `useState<newList []>([]);` if I haven't bunged up the syntax, in other words, it's an array of `newList` types, i.e. `newList[]`. Looks like `useState<Array<newList>>([]);` may also work. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays